# About $E(G)$ for a finite $p$-group $G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, gap

For any group $G$, the absolute center $L(G)$ of $G$ is defined as
$$L(G) = \lbrace g\in G\mid \alpha(g)=g,\forall\alpha\in Aut(G)
\rbrace$$, where $Aut(G)$ denote the group of all automorphisms of
$G$. An automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ is called an absolute central
automorphism if $g^{-1}\alpha(g)\in L(G)$ for all $g\in G$. Let
$Var(G)$ denote the group of all absolute central automorphisms of
$G$. Let
$$C_{Aut(G)}(Var(G))= \lbrace \alpha\in Aut(G)\mid\alpha\beta =
\beta\alpha, \forall\beta \in Var(G)\rbrace$$ denote the centralizer
of $Var(G)$ in $Aut(G)$.
Let $$E(G)=[G,C_{Aut(G)}(Var(G))]=\langle g^{-1}\alpha(g)\mid g\in
G, \alpha\in C_{Aut(G)}(Var(G))\rangle.$$ One can easily see that
$E(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$ containing the derived
group $G^{\prime}=[G,Inn(G)]$. Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, how to calculate $E(G)$ in GAP?

Comment: $E(G)$ is contained in the intersection of all kernels of homomorphisms $G\to L(G)$. Do they always coincide?

Comment: Now reposted at MSE at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226846/